# Do I need to create more functions? And also, is this code difficult to unit test?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm new to production code. And also I'm learning how to test code, I'll use the unittest module that comes with python to do that.
One more question, how can I make this code more safe?

```
  """
  Sync your iTunes files with your Android
  """
  import os, string, re, shutil
  from ctypes import windll

  def get_drives():
      drives = []
      bitmask = windll.kernel32.GetLogicalDrives()
      for letter in string.uppercase:
          if bitmask & 1:
              drives.append(letter)
          bitmask >>= 1

      return drives

  def get_android_dir():
     android_devices = []
     drives = get_drives()
     for drive in drives:
        path = drive + ':\\'      
        try:
           drive_dirs = os.listdir(path)         
           for diry in drive_dirs:
              if re.compile('android_secure', re.IGNORECASE).search(diry) != None:
                 android_devices.append(path)
                 #print path, 'is an Android device'
                 #print drive_dirs
                 break            
        except WindowsError: pass

     return android_devices

  def all_files_from_path_filtered(path):
      #files = []
      files = set()
      #print os.listdir(itunes_dir)
      for dirpath, dirname, filenames in os.walk(path):
          for filename in filenames:            
              if dirpath[-3:]!='tmp': # don't add files that are still been downloader
                  files.add(Filedata(filename, dirpath))
              else:
                  print 'Not syncing', dirpath.split('\\')[-1], "it's still downloading"
      return files

  def files_to_be_uploaded(itunes_dir, android_dir):
      itunes_set = all_files_from_path_filtered(itunes_dir)
      android_set = all_files_from_path_filtered(android_dir)

      #print 'iTunes Set', len(itunes_set), itunes_set
      #print 'Android Set', len(android_set), android_set

      to_upload_files = list(itunes_set.difference(android_set))        
      return to_upload_files

  class Filedata(object):
      def __init__(self, filename, path):
          self.filename = filename
          self.path = path + '\\' + filename
      def __eq__(self, other):        
          return self.filename==other.filename    
      def __hash__(self):        
          return self.filename.__hash__()
      def __repr__(self):
          return self.filename    

  def only_dirs_path(path):
      return ''.join([dirx + '\\' for dirx in path.split('\\')[:-1]])

  def file_size_appropriate(path):
      size = os.path.getsize(path)
      KBs = size / 1024
      if KBs <= 1024: # 1 MB
          return str(KBs) + ' KB'
      else:
          MBs = KBs / 1024
          return str(MBs) + ' MB'    

  def sync():
      android_dir = android_dirs[0] + 'music'
      to_upload_files = files_to_be_uploaded(itunes_dir, android_dir)

      num_files = len(to_upload_files)
      if num_files == 0:
          print 'Your Android is already synced to your iTunes'
          return
      if num_files!=1: 
          print 'Syncing', len(to_upload_files), 'files'
      else:
          print 'Syncing', 1, 'file'
      for filedata in to_upload_files:
          upload_path = android_dir + filedata.path.replace(itunes_dir, '')    

          print filedata, file_size_appropriate(filedata.path)

          upload_dir = only_dirs_path(upload_path)        
          if not os.path.exists(upload_dir):
              os.mkdir(upload_dir)
          shutil.copy2(filedata.path, upload_path)

      print 'Done. Your Android is Synced to your iTunes'

  user_dir = os.getenv('USERPROFILE')
  itunes_dir = user_dir + '\\Music\\iTunes\\iTunes Media'
  android_dirs = get_android_dir()
  if len(android_dirs) > 0:
      try:
          sync()
      except WindowsError as e:
          ex = str(e)[:9]
          if ex == '[Error 3]':
              print e
              print 'iTunes Still Downloading Error, aborting. Wait your downloads in iTunes to finish before syncing'            
          else:
              raise e
      #print to_upload_files      
  else:
     print "There's no Android device connected. Exiting"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"""
  Sync your iTunes files with your Android
  """
  import os, string, re, shutil
  from ctypes import windll

  def get_drives():
      drives = []
      bitmask = windll.kernel32.GetLogicalDrives()
```

I'd call this drives_bitmask just to be a bit clearer

```
      for letter in string.uppercase:
          if bitmask & 1:
              drives.append(letter)
          bitmask >>= 1
```

I think shifting the bitmaks makes it a little less clear what is going on. I'd do

```
for index, letter in enumerate(string.uppercase):
    if bitmask & (1 << index):
          drives.append(letter)


      return drives
```

This function will be somewhat difficult to test because it only ever returns the drives on your current computer. So it'll be hard to test for other computers with different drives. It might be better to pass the drive bitmask into the function.

```
  def get_android_dir():
     android_devices = []
     drives = get_drives()
     for drive in drives:
```

You don't need to store things in local variables. Just do `for drive in get_drives():`

```
        path = drive + ':\\'      
        try:
           drive_dirs = os.listdir(path)         
           for diry in drive_dirs:
```

I'd use directory rather then diry

```
              if re.compile('android_secure', re.IGNORECASE).search(diry) != None:
```

There isn't really any reason to be using a regular expression here. Just use `'android_secure' in diry.lower()`

```
                 android_devices.append(path)
                 #print path, 'is an Android device'
                 #print drive_dirs
```

Don't keep old code around in comments

```
                 break            
        except WindowsError: pass
```

Simply ignoring errors is almost always a bad idead

```
     return android_devices
```

This will be painful to unit test because to checks the physical drives.

```
  def all_files_from_path_filtered(path):
```

It'd be better if the name suggested the type of filtering

```
      #files = []
      files = set()
```

Don't leave old code in your file

```
      #print os.listdir(itunes_dir)
      for dirpath, dirname, filenames in os.walk(path):
          for filename in filenames:            
              if dirpath[-3:]!='tmp': # don't add files that are still been downloader
```

What if the filename is shorter then three characters? Use `dirpath.endswith` instead. Also, check `dirpath` outside of this loop.

```
                  files.add(Filedata(filename, dirpath))
              else:
                  print 'Not syncing', dirpath.split('\\')[-1], "it's still downloading"
      return files

  def files_to_be_uploaded(itunes_dir, android_dir):
      itunes_set = all_files_from_path_filtered(itunes_dir)
      android_set = all_files_from_path_filtered(android_dir)

      #print 'iTunes Set', len(itunes_set), itunes_set
      #print 'Android Set', len(android_set), android_set

      to_upload_files = list(itunes_set.difference(android_set))
```

Why convert back to a list?

```
      return to_upload_files

  class Filedata(object):
      def __init__(self, filename, path):
          self.filename = filename
          self.path = path + '\\' + filename
```

Use os.path.join to combine paths

```
      def __eq__(self, other):        
          return self.filename==other.filename    
      def __hash__(self):        
          return self.filename.__hash__()
      def __repr__(self):
          return self.filename
```

It might be an idea to move some of the logic into this class

```
  def only_dirs_path(path):
      return ''.join([dirx + '\\' for dirx in path.split('\\')[:-1]])
```

os.path has a number of useful function including dirname which will do this for you

```
  def file_size_appropriate(path):
```

Its not really appropriate as much as human readable

```
      size = os.path.getsize(path)
      KBs = size / 1024
      if KBs <= 1024: # 1 MB
          return str(KBs) + ' KB'
      else:
          MBs = KBs / 1024
          return str(MBs) + ' MB'    

  def sync():
      android_dir = android_dirs[0] + 'music'
      to_upload_files = files_to_be_uploaded(itunes_dir, android_dir)

      num_files = len(to_upload_files)
      if num_files == 0:
          print 'Your Android is already synced to your iTunes'
          return
```

I'd use an else block rather then a return

```
      if num_files!=1: 
          print 'Syncing', len(to_upload_files), 'files'
      else:
          print 'Syncing', 1, 'file'
      for filedata in to_upload_files:
          upload_path = android_dir + filedata.path.replace(itunes_dir, '')
```

Use os.path.relpath

```
          print filedata, file_size_appropriate(filedata.path)

          upload_dir = only_dirs_path(upload_path)        
          if not os.path.exists(upload_dir):
              os.mkdir(upload_dir)
          shutil.copy2(filedata.path, upload_path)

      print 'Done. Your Android is Synced to your iTunes'

  user_dir = os.getenv('USERPROFILE')
  itunes_dir = user_dir + '\\Music\\iTunes\\iTunes Media'
  android_dirs = get_android_dir()
```

This kinda thing should really be in a main function

```
  if len(android_dirs) > 0:
      try:
          sync()
      except WindowsError as e:
          ex = str(e)[:9]
          if ex == '[Error 3]':
```

Use `if str(e).beginswith('[Error 3]'):`

```
              print e
              print 'iTunes Still Downloading Error, aborting. Wait your downloads in iTunes to finish before syncing'            
          else:
              raise e
      #print to_upload_files      
  else:
     print "There's no Android device connected. Exiting"
```

Unit testing programs to read the filesystem is one of the harder things to unit test. If you are just starting unit testing, I don't recommend starting here.

Comment: You're suggesting this? upload_path = os.path.relpath(filedata.path, android_dir), if it is it throws ValueError: path is on drive C:, start on drive G:

Comment: @Vandell, no, `os.path.relpath(filedata.path, itunes_dir)`

Comment: Now I get it, I actually had to do more, os.path.join(android_dir, os.path.relpath(filedata.path, itunes_dir))